# How to simulate an Enter key in command mode?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Is it possible to simulate an Enter(i.e. `<CR>`) in command-mode, i.e. after pressing `:`?

Comment: what do you mean, execute `<cr>` in command-mode? I do not follow

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `:help c_CTRL-V` in the cmdline.txt section.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I want to use command to simulate pressing the Enter key.

Comment: As running command already involves enter key, it is strange. maybe you want `:h feedkeys`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mattb was saying in comments you need to check [`:h c_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-V) and you'll also need [`:h :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal).

The basic you'll need to use is:

```
:normal! ^M
```

Note that `^M` is not two literal characters, you have to input it by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The `!` after `normal` is to use the default `<CR>` key, it's important if you (or the users of your plugin) remapped `<CR>` to do other things.

---

Edit: Cf. Ben's comment: If you want to avoid special characters requiring `ctrl+v` you can use [`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to build you command and escape the special chars:

```
:execute "normal! \<cr>"
```

If you are running that "manually" from the command line I think the first option is easier but in a script it's better to use the more verbose form.

Comment: To avoid "special characters" like from C-v CR: `:execute "normal! \<cr>"`

Comment: Right thank you Ben! I wanted to add that in my answer but somehow I forgot about the `\` and decided to go the other way... I'm not doing as much vimscript as I used to, I losing the right reflexes :D